# Cómo usar OUTER APPLY en MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2017

quería saber como puedo transformar este OUTER APPLY ( Sql server sintaxis) para que sea compatible con MS ACCESS.

```
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Movimiento m
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 
                         costo 
                   FROM  dbo.Unitario u
                   WHERE u.Cod = m.Cod 
                   AND   u.Fecha <= m.Fecha 
                   ORDER BY u.Fecha DESC) u
```

Comment: No hay ninguna forma directa de hacerlo en access. El código que vas a necesitar no es nada simple....crear una query que sea un `INNER JOIN` de la tabla `Unitario` consigo misma para obtener el último registro para un código, y usar esa query en un `LEFT JOIN` con la tabla `Movimiento`

Comment: No existe el operador Apply en access. Sugiero que en lugar de plantear una pregunta sobre como _traducir_ de una sintaxis a otra, expliques cuál es el resultado que deseas obtener, o, lo que es lo mismo, qué es lo que hace dicha consulta, de manera que algún experto en access pueda ayudarte a construir algo que te de el resultado en dicho motor.

Answer (score 1):

Con una subquery se puede lograr:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (SELECT TOP 1 costo 
        FROM dbo.Unitario as u
        WHERE u.Cod = m.Cod AND
              u.Fecha <= m.Fecha 
        ORDER BY u.Fecha DESC
      ) as costo 
FROM dbo.Movimiento as m;
```